# Is it correct to say "Consumption of alcohol is injurious to health"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have written the two sentence,

1) Consumption of alcohol is injurious to health.
or
2) Consuming alcohol is injurious to health.

please tell me which one is correct and if the two sentences are correct then please tell me which should I use while speaking?

Comment: Please provide more details. Why have you written these two sentences? To whom might you want to speak about this subject?

Answer (score 1):

They're both fine - they are both grammatically correct and they mean the same thing.

Now, both sentences are not [entirely *factually* correct](http://www.medicaldaily.com/red-wine-burns-fat-and-lowers-blood-pressure-plus-5-other-health-benefits-winos-321382), but that's a matter for another discussion. :)